# Как создать поиск на диске

Tags: поиск

Как создать поиск по сайту, который помещен на компакт-диск и работает без подключения к сети?

Comment: Поиск в интернете, который работает без интернета?) Сами поняли?)

Comment: Это вы не поняли, сайт работает на диске автономно как обычная программа, нужен поиск по нему.

Comment: как обычный поиск по диску

Comment: можно попробовать написать на javascript, в формате *.hta, оно откроется как программа-браузер и сделать маленькую базу данных в файле. Я бы помог но яваскрипт плохо знаю

Comment: тогда уже лучше "компилированный" html (chm). Там и поиск по всем страницам будет.

Comment: Тьфу, я прочитал как "поиск ..., который на диске", каюсь. Тогда да, chm. Не ну можно весь контент сайта прогнать через strip_tags, потом куски запихнуть в дивы с `id="$filename"` и искать яваскриптом по этим дивам в ифрейме) И нет, я не наркоман)

Comment: Спасибо! А что можно почитать про этот chm, а то я ничего круче html c css не знаю)

Answer (score 2):

Смотря, как оно у вас сделано.

Если там **просто обычное открытие локально лежащих НТМЛ-файлов**, то только писать простой джава-скрипт, с ОТТТАКЕЕНЫМ массивом-индексом ключевых слов. При грамотном комбинировании индекс-файла(ов), и файла ссылок можно попытаться добиться стабильной работы даже на довольно больших объемах. Естественно "индексатор" прийдется ваять самому или искать что-то выдающее подходящий формат.

Если там есть что-то выполняющее функции **веб-сервера**, то в это что-то пишите скрипт/модуль/функцию, которая и будет искать.

Естественно поиск должен быть индексированный.

Самый простой способ совать все в sqlite-таблицу структурой типа link varchar(xx), body text с fulltext-индексом по полю `body` и поиском match-against запросом.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую разобраться.